# How to decorate WPF Panel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, custom-controls

I want to write a custom `Panel` that would make use of Decorator patern. That means it will have some other `Panel` as a property. When some element is added to my custom panel I want to add it also to decorated panel (stored in property) and when some element is removed, I want to remove it from decorated panel as well. How do I do that ?

Is there some method that is to be overriden or some event is fired when change to InternalCholdrens happen ?

Thank you

EDIT: Basicly I want to do something like [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-creating-a-custom-panel-control) I want to turn any panel to the animated one. So I want to decorate any panel with my decorator so it becomes animated.

Comment: what kind of animation do you expect to be able to do with "any panel"?  the different types of panels (grid, canvas, stackpanel, dockpanel, etc) have totally different capabilities for how they position items within them.  i don't see there being a generic way to do what you describe...

Comment: There is. But that's my know how and it is not easy to describe it. But the technical details are seems to be a problem for me :(

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, unfortunately.

What you will get immediately is an exception saying a control can have only one logical parent.

Although what you can do is to do double-delegation. Your panel delegates measure/arrange to another panel, and in return it provides it with 'ghosts' which will act as a children to it and delegate their own measure/arrange to your panel's children.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;

public class DelegatePanel : Panel
{
    private sealed class DelegateChild : FrameworkElement
    {
        readonly Func<Size, Size> measure;
        readonly Func<Size, Size> arrange;

        public DelegateChild(Func<Size,Size> measure, Func<Size,Size> arrange)
        {
            this.measure = measure;
            this.arrange = arrange;
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
        {
            return measure(availableSize);
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            return arrange(finalSize);
        }
    }

    readonly Dictionary<UIElement, UIElement> delegateByChild = new Dictionary<UIElement,UIElement>();

    public Panel LayoutPanel
    {
        get { return (Panel)GetValue(LayoutPanelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LayoutPanelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LayoutPanelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LayoutPanel", typeof(Panel), typeof(DelegatePanel), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        if(this.LayoutPanel==null)
            return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);

        this.delegateByChild.Clear();

        this.LayoutPanel.Children.Clear();
        foreach (UIElement _child in this.Children)
        {
            var child = _child;

            var delegateChild = new DelegateChild(
                    availableChildSize =>
                    {
                        child.Measure(availableChildSize);
                        return child.DesiredSize;
                    },
                    finalChildSize =>
                    {
                        return finalChildSize;
                    });

            delegateByChild[child] = delegateChild;

            this.LayoutPanel.Children.Add(delegateChild);
        }

        this.LayoutPanel.Measure(availableSize);
        return this.LayoutPanel.DesiredSize;
    }

    protected override Size  ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        if(this.LayoutPanel==null)
            return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);

        this.LayoutPanel.Arrange(new Rect(finalSize));

        foreach (var kv in delegateByChild)
        {
            var child = kv.Key;
            var delegateChild = kv.Value;

            var position = delegateChild.TranslatePoint(default(Point), this.LayoutPanel);

            Rect finalChildBounds = new Rect(
                position,
                delegateChild.RenderSize);

            child.Arrange(finalChildBounds);
        }

        return this.LayoutPanel.RenderSize;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: this doesn't implement VirtualizingPanel. So whilst it does work inside ItemsControl and the gang -- it won't perform quick enough for large collections.

Comment: When I first glanced at "double-delegation" I was sure you'd said *Although what you can do is to play [Double Dragon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Dragon).* With which I agree entirely. :)

Comment: Note, however, that things like DockPanel.Dock will not get propagated from your real children to ghost children for the delegated layout panel.

Answer (score 1):

i don't totally understand the context for this question but you can override OnVisualChildrenChanged

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.onvisualchildrenchanged.aspx

Comment: I was thinking the same way but is that a right practise ? Is OnVisualChildrenChanged also called when an element is added because of binding ? That would be desirable. In the other hand is OnVisualChildrenChanged changed when a border is added ? That is not desirable...